# Displayed equation is not centered

Tags: amsmath

I'm planning to send my research paper to a journal using the provided template. However, i found that displayed math is not centered (paper publish in the journal have equation centered). Below i provide the template and `oeko.cls` (not the whole, too long to be posted here) file of document class.

```
\documentclass[oeko]{oeko}
 %Remove any % below to load the required packages
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\title{Persistence......}
\titlerunning{Persistence.....}

\subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?} % Insert a subtitle or remove this line

\gertitle{F\"ugen Sie den dt. Titel hier ein}
\gersubtitle{Haben Sie einen dt. Untertitel?}

\author{Aidil .....}% etc
\thanks{Thanks...}}
\authorrunning{Aidil....}
%
\jel{Insert JEL here}
%
\keywords{Finite elements, Detonation, Safety} %end of abstract
%
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
My abstract
\end{abstract}

% Start
\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
Testing of FRUH was based on the premise that the log forward exchange rate $(f_t)$ provides an unbiased predictor of the future log spot rate $(s_{t+1})$ or $E_ts_{t+1}=f_t$ . By subtracting the log spot rate from both sides of the equation, we can obtain the UIP:
\begin{align}
E_ts_{t+1}-s_t=f_t-s_t
\end{align}
Following \cite{fama1984forward}, testing the hypothesis was based on the regression framework of equation (1):
\begin{align}
s_{t+1}-s_t=\beta_1+\beta_2(f_t-s_t)+\varepsilon_{t+1}
\end{align}
\section{Section title}
\label{sec:1}
and 

\end{document}

% end of file template.tex
```

Document class `oeko.cls` (Part of it, hopefully it is suffice to detect the issue)

```
% DOCUMENT CLASS -- version 1.1 for LaTeX2e
        \~}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{oeko}[2009/05/25
^^JLaTeX document class for Jahrb?cher - version 1.1]
\newcommand\@ptsize{}
\newif\if@restonecol
\newif\if@titlepage
\@titlepagefalse
\DeclareOption{a4paper}
   {\setlength\paperheight {297mm}%
    \setlength\paperwidth  {210mm}}
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{0}}
\DeclareOption{twoside}{\@twosidetrue  \@mparswitchtrue}
\DeclareOption{draft}{\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}}
\DeclareOption{final}{\setlength\overfullrule{0pt}}
\DeclareOption{onecolumn}{\@onecolumntrue}
\DeclareOption{fleqn}{\input{fleqn.clo}\AtEndOfClass{\mathindent\z@}}
\let\if@mathematic\iftrue
\let\if@numbook\iffalse
\DeclareOption{numbook}{\let\if@envcntsect\iftrue
  \AtEndOfPackage{%
   \renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection.\@arabic\c@figure}%
   \renewcommand\thetable{\thesection.\@arabic\c@table}%
   \renewcommand\theequation{\thesection.\@arabic\c@equation}%
   \@addtoreset{figure}{section}%
   \@addtoreset{table}{section}%
   \@addtoreset{equation}{section}%
  }%
}
\DeclareOption{openbib}{%
  \AtEndOfPackage{%
   \renewcommand\@openbib@code{%
      \advance\leftmargin\bibindent
      \itemindent -\bibindent
      \listparindent \itemindent
      \parsep \z@
      }%
   \renewcommand\newblock{\par}}%
}
%
\let\if@runhead\iffalse
\DeclareOption{runningheads}{\let\if@runhead\iftrue}
\let\if@smartrunh\iffalse
\DeclareOption{smartrunhead}{\let\if@smartrunh\iftrue}
\DeclareOption{nosmartrunhead}{\let\if@smartrunh\iffalse}
\let\if@envcntreset\iffalse
\DeclareOption{envcountreset}{\let\if@envcntreset\iftrue}
\let\if@envcntsame\iffalse
\DeclareOption{envcountsame}{\let\if@envcntsame\iftrue}
\let\if@envcntsect\iffalse
\DeclareOption{envcountsect}{\let\if@envcntsect\iftrue}
\let\if@referee\iffalse
\DeclareOption{referee}{\let\if@referee\iftrue}
\def\makereferee{\def\baselinestretch{2}}
\let\if@instindent\iffalse
\DeclareOption{instindent}{\let\if@instindent\iftrue}
\let\if@smartand\iffalse
\DeclareOption{smartand}{\let\if@smartand\iftrue}
\let\if@spthms\iftrue
\DeclareOption{nospthms}{\let\if@spthms\iffalse}
\let\switch@texts\relax
\DeclareOption{deutsch}{\def\switch@texts{\ds@deutsch}}
\DeclareOption{francais}{\def\switch@texts{\ds@francais}}
%
\let\journalopt\@empty
\DeclareOption*{\InputIfFileExists{oeko.clo}{%
\let\journalopt\CurrentOption}{%
\ClassWarning{Jahrbuecher}{Specified option or subpackage
"\CurrentOption" not found -}\OptionNotUsed}}
\ExecuteOptions{a4paper,twoside,10pt,instindent}
\ProcessOptions
\ifx\journalopt\@empty
\ClassError{Jahrbuecher}{No valid journal specified in option list}{}
\expandafter\stop
\fi
%
\if@smartrunh\AtEndDocument{\islastpageeven\getlastpagenumber}\fi
%
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Gamma}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"00}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Delta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"01}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Theta}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"02}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Lambda}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"03}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"04}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Pi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"05}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sigma}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"06}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upsilon}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"07}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Phi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"08}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Psi}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"09}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"0A}
%
\setlength\parindent{15\p@}
\setlength\smallskipamount{3\p@ \@plus 1\p@ \@minus 1\p@}
\setlength\medskipamount{6\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
\setlength\bigskipamount{12\p@ \@plus 4\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
\setlength\headheight{12\p@}
\setlength\headsep   {16.74dd}
\setlength\topskip   {10\p@}
\setlength\footskip{30\p@}
\setlength\maxdepth{.5\topskip}
%
\@settopoint\textwidth
\setlength\marginparsep {10\p@}
\setlength\marginparpush{5\p@}
\setlength\topmargin{-10pt}
\if@twocolumn
   \setlength\oddsidemargin {-30\p@}
   \setlength\evensidemargin{-30\p@}
\else
   \setlength\oddsidemargin {\z@}
   \setlength\evensidemargin{\z@}
\fi
\setlength\marginparwidth  {48\p@}
\setlength\footnotesep{8\p@}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{9\p@ \@plus 4\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
\setlength\floatsep    {12\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
\setlength\textfloatsep{20\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
\setlength\intextsep   {20\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
\setlength\dblfloatsep    {12\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
\setlength\dbltextfloatsep{20\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
\setlength\@fptop{0\p@}
\setlength\@fpsep{12\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
\setlength\@fpbot{0\p@ \@plus 1fil}
\setlength\@dblfptop{0\p@}
\setlength\@dblfpsep{12\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@}
\setlength\@dblfpbot{0\p@ \@plus 1fil}
\setlength\partopsep{2\p@ \@plus 1\p@ \@minus 1\p@}
\def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
            \parsep \z@
            \topsep 6\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
            \itemsep\parsep}
\let\@listI\@listi
\@listi
\def\@listii {\leftmargin\leftmarginii
              \labelwidth\leftmarginii
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
              \topsep    \z@
              \parsep    \topsep
              \itemsep   \parsep}
\def\@listiii{\leftmargin\leftmarginiii
              \labelwidth\leftmarginiii
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
              \topsep    \z@
              \parsep    \topsep
              \itemsep   \parsep}
\def\@listiv {\leftmargin\leftmarginiv
              \labelwidth\leftmarginiv
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
\def\@listv  {\leftmargin\leftmarginv
              \labelwidth\leftmarginv
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
\def\@listvi {\leftmargin\leftmarginvi
              \labelwidth\leftmarginvi
              \advance\labelwidth-\labelsep}
  %% End of file `oeko.cls'.
```

Comment: `\begin{center}\begin{align}..blabla...\end{align}\end{center}` could possible do... and welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Unfortunately, the code you've posted needs a lot of debugging before it can function as an MWE. E.g., a `%` is missing at the start of the line after `\documentclass`. Your chances of getting a solution to the question you pose will increase sharply if you put in the basic effort to make the code compilable.

Comment: Hai Christian, I have try that before. still not centered.

Comment: Hai Mico, the code is too long. I'm not sure which part that i can cut that can make the code still compilable.

Comment: Where could we get the whole `oeko.cls`?

Comment: http://www.jbnst.de/download/latex-style-files.rar

Comment: Here is the link Bernard, http://www.jbnst.de/download/latex-style-files.rar

Comment: Left alignment is coded in lines 306-309 of the class file, mainly: `\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}` and I don't know how to call the option off. What I can suggest is changing the math margin to a positive value (2em in my example) with this line in the preamble :
`\makeatletter
\setlength{\@mathmargin}{2em}
\makeatother`.

Comment: it works well Bernard

Comment: If the class is provided by the journal to which you are submitting the paper, just use the class as-is. If the journal wants the equations centered, it is their job to make it so.

Answer (score 2):

@Bernard pointed out in a comment that left alignment is specified in the class file (lines 306-309) by `\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}`.  he suggested changing the math margin to a positive value by adding these lines to the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@mathmargin}{2em}
\makeatother
```

this was tried, with positive effect.

a modification that will undo the `amsmath` setting more completely is this:

```
\makeatletter
\@fleqnfalse
\@mathmargin\@centering
\makeatother
```

however, this comment by @Paul Gessler should be considered seriously:

> If the class is provided by the journal to which you are submitting the paper, just use the class as-is. If the journal wants the equations centered, it is their job to make it so.

Comment: That last point only makes sense if the author doesn't care about whether the equations are centered, but clearly someone asking this question doesn't like the non-centered equations!